# Thread & Process PoolExecutor with workers that keep state

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

For a FTP download problem at scale I'd like to use Python's [concurrent futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to get multiple FTP connections and have each download multiple files.

My question is how can I make workers that can keep their state such that I don't have to reconnect the FTP for each file I download?

Ideally I'd do something like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor

class FTP_Worker:
    def __init__(self, idn):
        self.idn = idn
        self.connection = ftplib.connect(server, password)
        
    def downloadfile(filename):
        self.connection.download(filename)
        
workers = [FTP_Worker(i) for i in range(12)]
filenames = filenames # list of 1000s remote files

Executor(max_workers=12).map(workers, filenames)
```

And ideally this works for both ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: The connection (or whatever should be stored for each thread/process) should be created in this thread/process (if not present yet) and stored in an attribute of a previously created `thread.local` object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some comments:

First, you did not provide a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so in the code below I have commented out FTP-related calls and have instead added some `print` statements so that you can follow what is going on.

Second, the `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` method takes as a first argument a function. You are instead passing it a list of `FTP_Worker` instances. This is clearly not going to work. But I see, based on the code you posted, no need for such a class.

Third, you are using a multiprocessing pool. But since your code appears to require no intensive CPU processing, a multithreading pool I have opted to use class `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead. But you should be able to replace this with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` and the code should still work.

Fourth, "thread local" storage is used to hold one reusable FTP connection for each thread/process in your pool so that the 12 connections can be reused for your many downloads. But rather than keeping the connection in thread local storage, I am storing a special `Connector` class instance that wraps the connection so that when the threads/processes that constitute the pool are destroyed, the connections will be closed.

You will, of course, need to supply the missing definitions and un-comment the code that does the FTP-related operations:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor
import threading

threadLocal = threading.local()

class Connector:
    def __init__(self, server, password):
        raise Exception('You must call the get_connection class method instead of __init__')

    @classmethod
    def get_connection(cls):
        connector = getattr(threadLocal, 'connector', None)
        if connector is None:
            connector = cls.__new__(cls)
            # ftplib, server and password are not defined, so for demo we comment
            # the following out and assign None to the connection:
            #connector.connection = ftplib.connect(self._server, self._password)
            connector.connection = None
            # Just print out this for demo purposes
            print('creating new connector')
            threadLocal.connector = connector
        return connector.connection

    def __del__(self):
        # Comment out the following since for this demo there is no connection:
        #self._connection.close()
        print('closing connection')

def downloadfile(idn, filename):
    connection = Connector.get_connection()
    # We don't have an actual connection, so:
    #connection.download(filename)
    # To emulate network download time:
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print(idn, filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filenames = [f'fn{i}' for i in range(1, 21)]
    idns = range(1, len(filenames) + 1)

    with Executor(max_workers=12) as executor:
        executor.map(downloadfile, idns, filenames)
    # Now the pool will be shutdown and connections closed
    print('Downloads completed.')
```

Prints:

```None
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
creating new connector
11 fn11
9 fn9
8 fn8
6 fn6
4 fn4
1 fn1
10 fn10
7 fn7
2 fn2
12 fn12
3 fn3
5 fn5
closing connection
closing connection
closing connection
closing connection
18 fn18
19 fn19
14 fn14
13 fn13
closing connection
closing connection
closing connection
closing connection
15 fn15
16 fn16
closing connection
closing connection
17 fn17
closing connection
20 fn20
closing connection
Downloads completed.
```

Comment: I think this will make a new connection for each download. I want to make n connections with n threads to download m files. With m >> n.

Comment: No, no, no. If you count the number of "creating new connection" messages there are n = 12 of them, one for each thread in the multithreading pool. The number of downloads, m, is 20. Connections are being reused!

Comment: @Bastiaan Did you downvote this and if so would you do me the favor of telling me why?

Comment: @Bastiaan Are you still not convinced that this uses only 12 connections, one for each pool thread, for all of the downloads?

Comment: Ah, yes, I get it now. Through the use of `threading.local`. I'm surprised we use two separate libraries for this, I guess it won't work for ProcessPoolExecutor, still, useful to know this method. Thanks!

Comment: It should work for `ProcessPoolExecutor` also., as I indicated in my answer If you now get it, consider accepting the answer (and maybe even upvoting it).